# Asp.net Bundle does {version} include min.js and non-min?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bundle

I have some scripts in my directory:

- jquery-2.1.4.js
- jquery-2.1.4.min.js
- jquery-2.1.4.intellisense.js

What does the below bundle include? Does it include the jquery-2.1.4.js and jquery-2.1.4.min.js? If so why would we want to do this? Won't it just slow down the website by loading same scripts that are not needed.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js").Include(
                                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Comment: Also in addition to Philip Smith's answer; {version} maps to a version regex.So it would include all matches, if you had multiple versions in the same directory you probably would not want to use this.Specify the version or delete old versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bundle that you have defined will load jquery-2.1.4.js when compiled as debug. However when compiled as release the min version will replace it. In this way you get the un-minified version when debugging, but the minified version in production.